# Can I hide column but no trendline in Google Charts?

Tags: charts

I've got a Google Line Chart with date column and few numeric columns. I've also added the numeric "average" column. And for this average i want to display trendline but don't want to display average data points.

When i use this, there is no data for avg column but there is also no trendline:

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
dataTable.hideColumns([5]);
```

How would I be able to still load column average's trendline, but just hide the column so that it is values not getting displayed? Every little help would be much appreciated.